# python "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python, numpy, loops, nested, integer

This is the code which is produing the error:

```py
import numpy as np
   
for i in range(len(x)):
    if (np.floor(N[i]/2)==N[i]/2):
        for j in range(N[i]/2):
            pxd[i,j]=x[i]-(delta*j)*np.sin(s[i]*np.pi/180)
            pyd[i,j]=y[i]-(delta*j)*np.cos(s[i]*np.pi/180)
           
    else:
        for j in range((N[i]-1)/2):
            pxd[i,j]=x[i]-(delta*j)*np.sin(s[i]*np.pi/180)
            pyd[i,j]=y[i]-(delta*j)*np.cos(s[i]*np.pi/180)
```

Does anyone have an idea as to how to solve this problem? How can I get the code to run successfully?

Comment: Why not lose the `if` and do... `for j in range(int(np.floor(N[i]/2)))`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
N=np.floor(np.divide(l,delta))
...
for j in range(N[i]/2):
```

`N[i]/2` will be a `float64` but `range()` expects an integer. Just cast the call to

```
for j in range(int(N[i]/2)):
```

Comment: I use Pyzo to run again, but it also reports type error: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'

Comment: well just see if you're doing the same mistake again; line numbers are not just for fun in the traceback.

Answer (score 11):

I came here with the same Error, though one with a different origin.

> It is caused by unsupported float index in 1.12.0 and newer numpy versions
>   even if the code should be considered as valid.

An `int` type is expected, not a `np.float64`

Solution: Try to install `numpy 1.11.0`

```
sudo pip install -U numpy==1.11.0.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems when I was training a retained object detection model (faster RCNN) and this worked for me perfectly:

```
pip uninstall pycocotools
pip install pycocotools-windows
```

Comment: There is no link with the question. Is there one ?

Answer (score 2):

While I appreciate this is not the OP's problem, I just had this error message for a very different reason and this is the top result so I'm posting my problem and resolution here.

I had this code:

```
x = np.ndarray([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=np.float_)
```

Notice the subtle mistake? `ndarray` is the numpy array class, but you usually don't construct it directly. Instead you use the `array()` helper function:

```
x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=np.float_)
```

Switching to the second form solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Similar situation. It was working. Then, I started to include pytables. At first view, no reason to errors. I decided to use another function, that has a domain constraint (elipse) and received the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

or

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

The crazy thing: the previous function I was using, no code changed, started to return the same error. My intermediary function, already used was:

```
def MinMax(x, mini=0, maxi=1)
    return max(min(x,mini), maxi)
```

The solution was avoid `numpy` or `math`:

```
def MinMax(x, mini=0, maxi=1)
    x = [x_aux if x_aux > mini else mini for x_aux in x]
    x = [x_aux if x_aux < maxi else maxi for x_aux in x]
    return max(min(x,mini), maxi)
```

Then, everything calm again. It was like one library possessed `max` and `min`!

Comment: This approach will work, but you can't always be a nigilist of numpy, math libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur when we use an old version of numpy.  In my case, I was using 1.18.5.  I upgraded to 1.19.5 and the fail finished.
After this, if you are using Jupyter, you shall shutdown Kernell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running any Object detection algorithm and facing this issue, it is because of version conflicts in '`pycocotools`'.  Uninstall and reinstall it, your problem will be solved.

```
pip uninstall pycocotools
pip install pycocotools
```