# How to apply clustering on sentences embeddings?

Tags: cluster-analysis, summarization, sentence-similarity

I would like to create a summary with the major points of the original document. To do this, I made sentences embeddings with a Universal Sentence Encoder(https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2). After, I would like apply clustering on my vectors.

I've tried with the library `sklearn`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

n_clusters = np.ceil(len(encoded)**0.5)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
kmeans = kmeans.fit(encoded)
```

But I get an error message:

```
'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'
```

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/24003477/3514144

Comment: Thank you @AjayPandya but I have an other error message like "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Comment: you can use like  kmeans.astype(int) for more read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36680545/3514144 :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused in this line:

```
n_clusters = np.ceil(len(encoded)**0.5)
```

`kmeans` expects to receive an `integer` as the number of clusters so simply add:

```
n_clusters = int(np.ceil(len(encoded)**0.5))
```