# What is the problem with the type error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, typeerror

So while I was doing my assignment, the code here does not work at all because a type error. I checked everything and it seems all right. why does this happen? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76c3Z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JblcS.png)

Comment: Please put your actual code as text in the question, not an image.

Comment: What are you passing in as `n` to `get_batch2()`?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting seems to occur when you try to get a numpy array of random numbers (`np.random.randint()`). It looks like you are passing a float as argument `n` in `get_batch2()`. You can floor that float and convert it to an integer using `.astype(np.int64)`.

Put simply, a `numpy.float64` object cannot be used as an integer in your code; they are different data types. You must do some kind of operation to the float to turn it into an integer. Integers can't hold all the data a float can (an integer cannot store the decimal part of a number) so you have to do something like rounding the float to the nearest integer or etc. The `.astype(np.int64)` method will return the floored float or array of floats etc. in the numpy.int64 type.

It seems that versions of numpy 1.12.0 and above will raise this exception. If for any reason you wanted to not have to deal with converting to an integer, one of the solutions is installing numpy with version to 1.11.0 or below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44669924/12076702

Comment: Thank you for your response. One quick question, where should I put this line of code?

Comment: If what you are passing in as `n` is a `numpy.float64` instead of an integer, then replace `picks = np.random.randint(0, len(stock_path) - 1, n)` with `picks = np.random.randint(0, len(stock_path) - 1, n.astype(np.int64))`.