# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer fake news detection

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting this error and not able to resolve it and not able to find it on the internet.

```
    TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-33f2a17ec582> in <module>
     20         print("Saving New CSV file")
     21 if __name__=='__main__':
---> 22         dataSetExtraction()

<ipython-input-10-33f2a17ec582> in dataSetExtraction()
      6         dfReal=processRealNewsDataFrame(dfReal)
      7         dfCombine=[]
----> 8         for d in extractTopRealResultsForCrawling(dfReal):
      9                 print('len of datadrame :',d['URL'].size)
     10                 #d=d[:100]

<ipython-input-6-9dbfd3f21499> in extractTopRealResultsForCrawling(dfReal)
      6     listOfIndex=[]
      7     df=[]
----> 8     for i in range(0,loop):
      9         listOfIndex.append(dfReal[i*10000:(i+1)*10000])
     10         df+=[dfReal[i*10000:(i+1)*10000]]

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is code giving the error. I have not been able to remove the error Please help me

```
def extractTopRealResultsForCrawling(dfReal):
    print("Retrieve top 20000 Real news data")
    num=dfReal.size
    loop=num/10000
    listOfIndex=[]
    df=[]
    for i in range(0,loop):
        listOfIndex.append(dfReal[i*10000:(i+1)*10000])
        df+=[dfReal[i*10000:(i+1)*10000]]   
    #print "length of dataframe array retrieved:",len(df[0])
    return df[:LEN]
```

Comment: This published info is not sufficient, publishing sample code helps

Comment: Well,  did you *read* the error message? Do you understand what an integer is? Do you understand what a `'numpy.float64' object` is? Does it make sense to you that this "cannot be interpreted as an integer"? Why or why not? Do you understand why the code is trying to use an integer here? Do you know which value is causing the problem? Were you expecting it to be an integer already? Why or why not?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003431/python-typeerror-numpy-float64-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer help? I found it by copying and pasting the title of your question into a search engine. It was the first result. When you say that you were "not able to resolve it and not able to find it on the internet", what exactly did *you* do?

Answer (score 0):

The `range` function can only receive **integer** values

Here is a minimal code reproducing (more or less) the problem:

```
>>> a = 2.0
>>> [i for i in range(a)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    [i for i in range(a)]
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

You need to convert the value to an integer

```
>>> [i for i in range(int(a))]
[0, 1]
```

In your code you should use:

```
for i in range(int(loop)):
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
for i in range(0, num, 10000):
    listOfIndex.append(dfReal[i:i+10000])
    df+=[dfReal[i:i+10000]]
```

avoiding the division...